# Firebug for ie7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, firebug

Is there is any **firebug** for ie7. In firefox firebug reduces lot of my work while checking code. In a same way ie supports firebug.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) is Firebug for non Firefox browsers.

If you haven't already, you can also try [IE developer toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535).

Comment: But you can't single-step through script code, set breakpoints, etc. with either of those, can you?

Comment: @T.J.: I haven't tried either of them (gave up long ago trying to make something work on IE exclusively), so I cannot comment. Still, these tools are better than nothing.

Answer (score 4):

It's not Firebug (but then, neither is Firebug Lite, really), but there's the free version of Visual Studio.Net, [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/), which provides a full script debugger and DOM inspection tool that connects to IE7. Set breakpoints, walk through code, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=95E06CBE-4940-4218-B75D-B8856FCED535&displaylang=en) in ie7

Comment: You can't walk through code (e.g., in a debugger), set breakpoints, etc. with the dev toolbar, though, right?